# Weird bug with JavaScript object property staring with underscore

Tags: javascript, properties, naming-conventions

I have a variable set for a DOM item called `lens`.
and when i tried to access a property of `lens` with underscore `lens._timeout` it is not working properly but when i changed it to 
`lens.timeout` it works as intended.

Code:

```
var lens = document.querySelector("#lens1");

if (lens._timeout) {
    clearTimeout(lens._timeout);
}

lens._timeout = setTimeout(function() { setLens(lens); }, 300);
```

This code works everywhere except in Safari. But works if I use lens.timeout instead.

Comment: The timeout is using a variable called `lend`. Maybe that's a typo (lend != lens) and could be the source of your problem.

Comment: Are you able to use the web inspector in Safari to see what the value of `lens._timeout` is after you set it to the result of `setTimeout`?

Comment: oops, yes, it is a typo - I did have the right spelling in my code (lens, not lend)

Comment: In Safari, the timeout variable (or lens property to be exact) is and remains undefined - while it's set in other browsers after the setTimeout runs.